# How to conditionally join with field's value of a entity by JPA or Hibernate annotations?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

How do I fetch entity informations depends on a field value ?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "src_type")
    private Long sourceType;

    @Column(name = "src_id")
    private Long sourceId;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "src_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Company company;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "src_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;

}
```

I would like to fetch `Company` information with `sourceId` value of `Tranaction` entity when `sourceType`'s value is *"COMPANY"* and `User` information with `sourceId` value of `Tranaction` entity when `sourceType`'s value is *"USER"*.

How can I achieve it with JPA or Hibernate annotations ?

For an example : a transaction record with ID '1' has sourceType = 'USER' and sourceId = 1 , then I would like to fetch `User` value from user table with related id = 1 but I don't want to join and fetch `Company` value from company table with id = 1 because **sourceType**'s value is not 'Company'.

I've also tried with below annotations like

```
//  @SQLRestriction("sourceType = 'COMPANY'")
//  @SQLJoinTableRestriction("sourceType = 'COMPANY'")
//  @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({@JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value = "sourceType = 'COMPANY'", referencedColumnName = "sourceId"))})
//  @JoinFormula(value = "sourceType = 'COMPANY'", referencedColumnName = "sourceId")
```

but didn't worked as I expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spring data jpa tables joining by One to one Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564089/spring-data-jpa-tables-joining-by-one-to-one-association)

Comment: @rafavilomar No , I don't think that question is not similar with my question and answers from that question didn't helped what I would like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@JoinFormula(value = "(case when (src_type = 'COMPANY') then src_id else null end)")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Company company;

@JoinFormula(value = "(case when (src_type = 'USER') then src_id else null end)")
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private User user;
```

Note: In my case @OneToOne causes error, I suppose because with the formula Hibernate cannot be sure that the association is unique.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as you said I got error `Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.mapping.Column.getName()" because the return value of "org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.AnnotatedJoinColumn.getMappingColumn()" is null` .

Comment: Yes. I suppose OneToOne is logically incorrect - I don't think you have only one transaction for each user/company. So it's the ManyToOny to be here.